# The Date is a Day Ahead

Tags: iphone

The date on my iphone is a day ahead and creating the wrong dates for emails and tests and such.  Anyway that I can reset it or rewind it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings->General->Date & Time and switch "Set Automatically" on. This should sync the time your iPhone has with Apple's servers, correcting the problem.